# Windows services using domain accounts cannot logon after VM restart

Tags: service, winlogon, gmsa

We have an issue when restarting VMs where services are not starting after the restart. The services are configured to use domain accounts and set to startuptype automatic.
We tried different account "types" for our services.

Used operating system: Windows server 2022 on client and DC

**GMSA account**

EventLog: The service was unable to log on as domain\gmsa$ with the currently configured password due to the following error:
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

**Account in format user@domain**

EventLog: The service failed to start due to the following error:
The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified.

**Account in format domain\user**

Service is state running after the VM restart

When we logon to that machine and start the services manually everything is working fine.
Setting the service to delayedstart its as well working fine.

Does someone have an idea why the GMSA account and the account in style user@domain behave different to an account in style domain\user?